# Should I use cookie to store information to track user in application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, cookies

I need to increase speed of my application but I must also watch on security. First I will explain what app do:
When user register in application he choose school, in user profile in database I store ID of this school.
Every school has it's own page and if user is from that school he can do some things on that school page, write comment's add pictures etc.
User can also visit other school pages but he can't write comments and add pictures.
Currently I keep `CurrentSchoolID` in `ViewBag's`.
I wonder is it better to store `CurrentSchoolID` in cookie.
Is it possible that some evil user user this cookie to harm application?

For application user must have cookies enabled.

Comment: Storing it in Session or Cookie should be just fine, just remember as always to error check the id before you send it into the db (for sql injections). It really all boils down to how you handle the sql stuff in terms of security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If users are not allowed to edit other schools but theirs, you can't count on the ID from the cookie to be true.

Theoretically, what you can do is to save the school ID in a cookie indeed, and upon every write/update/delete action, check (on the server of course) that the logged in user is eligible to alter data related to this school ID.

But in fact, the school ID is unnecessary. Better off - check on the server side which school this user is allowed to edit, and allow the edit operation only if the user edits one of this school's data.

Comment: SchoolID is necessary because that how I track on what school page user is currently. But that check on CRUD is important as you suggested,